# Cropping georeferenced map JPEG within QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip, georeferencing, jpg, geology

I have a geology map I georeferenced in QGIS, but I want to crop out the edges/margins/legend because I have other geology maps I want to georeference and stitch next to it, but the unused margins of the paper would overlap onto the maps. Is there a way I can crop these out within the QGIS?

I want to crop around the blue line I drew with paint in the example

[image]

Comment: If you create the drawn blue polygon as a true polygon, then just use Raster - Extraction - Clip raster by mask layer.

Comment: This answered my question, thanks! If you put it as an answer reply I'll mark it as answered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the drawn blue polygon as a true polygon, then just use Raster - Extraction - Clip raster by mask layer.